# IPython reloading different module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, ipython, reload

I made a test of shadowing Python's built-in string module with my own
module named 'string', to test module search path behavior. My custom
string script has only `print('string' * 2)` for contents. It is
located in the current directory as shown in code below.

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %pwd
Out[1]: 'C:\\Users\\stephen'

In [2]: import string

In [3]: string
Out[3]: <module 'string' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\string.py'>

In [4]: import imp

In [5]: imp.reload(string)
stringstring
Out[5]: <module 'string' from 'C:\\Users\\stephen\\string.py'>
```

Three questions about reload in IPython:

1. Why did reload think the module it actually imported (the local string.py) had already been imported? Is it just the sameness of file
   name?
2. Why did reload import a different module than the one already imported? Did it skip the check of sys.modules dictionary, which was
   checked first during original import?
3. Why did reload/IPython/Python not know it had pulled a fast one here, switching one module for another?

Edit: In going back and forth trying to take care of Stack Overflow complaining about my code block, I inadvertently lost some of what I meant to say. Here is what I can remember:
IPython is adding the built-in string module to sys.modules dictionary at startup (sys.modules is searched before sys.path), something the regular Python interactive prompt doesn't do. So I got a different behavior from the interactive prompt vs. IPython. With the interactive prompt, I always got the local string.py, since sys.path starts with current directory for module search. So, this much I understand about the difference between regular interactive (Anaconda) and IPython. The questions I listed are what remain confusing for me.

Comment: I would avoid using module names that already exist. This is prone to causing problems.

Comment: @JackMoody Yes, for sure. I wouldn't use such a name for my own module, normally. This was just an exercise meant to explore and understand better that kind of conflict. Now I'm trying to understand the results I didn't expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reload` is *supposed* to repeat the process of locating the source code for the module it's reloading, and if it finds a different file from what the original import found, it's *supposed* to use the new file. After all, it needs to handle cases where a module was moved, or where a normal module was changed to a package or an extension module.

`reload` is *not* supposed to look at `sys.modules` and stop if it finds something. If it did that, it would perform no reloading!

The reason `reload` finds the local `string.py` file when the initial IPython-internal import didn't is because the import path has changed since the first import. You ran IPython in a way that doesn't cause Python itself to put the working directory on the module search path, and IPython imported the `string` module from the standard library under that configuration. Afterward, IPython placed the working directory on the module search path itself, mimicking regular interactive Python, so `reload` found the local `string.py`.

Comment: Thanks. I flagged your response as answer. I will say, however, that if I check sys.path immediately after IPython starts, it *does* have empty string at start of this list, indicating working directory is searched first.

Comment: @StephenFrost: If by "immediately after IPython starts", you mean at the In[1] prompt, then that's after IPython has done all its startup work and edited `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

[Tested on my Kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc84t.png)

Looks you are using a local module name that shadows the name of a standard library or third party package or module that the application relies on. Python imports usually check from the the sys.path setting which might be set under Users\stephen. Hence when we reload it, it picks the first occurrence. Hope it helps.

For reference: https://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Comment: Thanks. Good reference link. Yes, I shadowed on purpose, to explore import behavior (to make sure I understand exactly how importing works internally--I don't). I will add that Users\stephen was *not* in sys.path in the scenario I described in my question.